# Combat system Crits

Tags: python

I'd like to make crits in my combat system but I'm stumped can someone help? I looked at someone else's but it wouldn't work for my code, can you help. My friend wanted a reliable combat system that functions efficiently. I made this to help them but the gosh darn crits are confusing me. I would love an explanation on how to fix it. Thanks a lot for helping! :D

```
#this if for a combat mechanism
import random
def end(enemy_health,your_health):
    if your_health > 0:
        print("  ")
        print("You slay the Ork")
    else:
        print("  ")
        print("You were slain...")
def your_first():   
    enemy_health = 20
    your_health =20
    while your_health > 0 and enemy_health > 0:
        your_damage = random.choice(range(7,13))
        enemy_health -= your_damage
        if enemy_health <= 0:
            enemy_health = 0
            print(" ")
            print("You dealt " + str(your_damage) + " damage!")
            print("Enemy's health:" + str(enemy_health))
            end(enemy_health,your_health)
        else:
            print(" ")
            print("You dealt " + str(your_damage) + " damage!")
            print("Enemy's health:" + str(enemy_health))
            enemy_damage = random.choice(range(9, 21))
            your_health -= enemy_damage
            if your_health <= 0:
                your_health = 0
                print("  ")
                print("Ork dealt " + str(enemy_damage) + " damage!")
                print("Your health:" + str(your_health))
                end(enemy_health,your_health)
            else:
                print("  ")
                print("Ork dealt " + str(enemy_damage) + " damage!")
                print("Your health:" + str(your_health))
def enemy_first():  
    enemy_health = 20
    your_health =20
    while your_health > 0 and enemy_health > 0:
    enemy_damage = random.choice(range(9, 21))
    your_health -= enemy_damage
    if your_health <= 0:
        your_health = 0
        print("  ")
        print("Ork dealt " + str(enemy_damage) + " damage!")
        print("Your health:" + str(your_health))
        end(enemy_health,your_health)
    else:
        print(" ")
        print("Ork dealt " + str(enemy_damage) + " damage!")
        print("Your health:" + str(your_health))
        your_damage = random.choice(range(7,13))
        enemy_health -= your_damage
        if enemy_health <= 0: 
            print(" ")
            print("You dealt " + str(your_damage) + " damage!")
            print("Enemy's health:" + str(enemy_health))
            end(enemy_health,your_health)
        else:
            print("  ")
            print("You dealt " + str(your_damage) + " damage!")
            print("Enemy's health:" + str(enemy_health))

print("(+)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(+)")
print(" | Damage:         | ")
print(" | 7-12            | ")
print(" | Speed:          | ")
print(" | 6/10            | ")
print(" | Critical Chance:| ")
print(" | 64%             | ")
print("(+)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(+)")
print("  ")
print("You encountered an Ork")
enemy = "Ork"
print("  ")
print("(+)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(+)")
print(" |Ork |  Health: 20| ")
print(" |-----------------| ")
print(" |Damage:      9-20| ")
print(" |-----------------| ")
print(" |Speed:       2/10| ")
print(" |-----------------| ")
print(" |Crit Chance:  13%| ")
print("(+)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(+)")
print("You engage the Ork in a battle!")
your_crit = (1, 65)
enemy_crits = (1, 13)
your_speed = 6
ork_speed = 2
if ork_speed >= your_speed:
    print("The " + enemy + " is faster, it attacks first!")
    enemy_first()
else:
    print("You're faster and get to attack first!")
    your_first()
```

Comment: At the very least you have to tell us what a critical hit should do and when a critical hit should occur. Then tell us what you have tried and how it does not work.

Comment: What, exactly, is confusing about the crits?

Comment: I wanted it to a set damage for a crit but its how to make the crits work. I don't know if that is what you wanted for clarification...

Comment: I wanted it to a set damage for a crit but its how to make the crits work. I don't know if that is what you wanted for clarification... I was thinking if you had a crit chance of 64% then then rng would choose a # from 1-100 the if  your_crit <=65% : print("Critical Strike!")